# How can we remove a customValidity message on keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

My problem is that when I set a customValidity to an input (`#zip_code`), it doesn't stop displaying it everytime I update this input (I'm using it in a keyup event and using `setCustomValidity('')` doesn't resolve the issue)

I've this html :

```html
<input type="text"  required placeholder="Nom"         name="lastname"     class="col-md-6 form-control"                                                 />
<input type="text"  required placeholder="Prénom"      name="firstname"    class="col-md-6 form-control"                                                 />
<input type="text"  required placeholder="Adresse"     name="address"      class="col-md-12 form-control"                                                />
<input type="text"  required placeholder="Code Postal" name="zip_code"     class="col-md-6 form-control"  id="zip_code" data-inputmask="'mask': '99999'" />
<input type="text"  required placeholder="Ville"       name="city"         class="col-md-6 form-control disabled"  id="city"                             />
<input type="text"  required placeholder="Téléphone"   name="phone_number" class="col-md-12 form-control" data-inputmask="'mask': '99 99 99 99 99'"      />
<input type="email" required placeholder="Email"       name="email"        class="col-md-12 form-control"                                                />
```

and this javascript :

```js
var zipCode = "";
$('#zip_code').keyup(function() {
    zipLength = zipCode.split('_')[0].length
    if (zipLength < 5 || zipLength == 5 && $( this ).val().split('_')[0].length != 5) {
        zipCode = $( this ).val();
        $('#city').replaceTag('<input>', true);
        $('#city').addClass('disabled');
        $('#city').focus(function(){$("#zip_code").focus();});
        $('#zip_code')[0].setCustomValidity("Veuillez renseigner un code postal valide.");
        $('#city').attr('tabindex', -1);
        $('#city').attr("placeholder", zipCode.length == 0 ? "Ville" : "Aucune ville pour ce code postal");
        $('#city').html('');
        if (zipCode.length == 5) {
            $.ajax( {
                url: "an url to a json representating every city having the zipCode",
                dataType: "json",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    zipCode: zipCode
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    data.cities.map( function( x, i ) {
                        let cityName = x.name.charAt(0) + x.name.substr(1).toLowerCase().trim();
                        if (i == 0) {
                            if (data.cities.length > 1) {
                                $('#city').removeClass('disabled');
                                $('#city').replaceTag( '<select>', true );
                                $("#city").append( new Option( cityName, cityName, true ) );
                            } else {
                                $('#city').addClass('disabled');
                                $('#zip_code')[0].setCustomValidity("Veuillez renseigner un code postal valide.");
                                $('#city').focus(function(){$("#zip_code").focus();});
                                $('#city').val( cityName );
                            }
                        } else {
                            $("#city").append( new Option( cityName, cityName ) );
                        }
                    } );
                }
            } );
        }
    }
});
$(":input").inputmask();
```

So as you can see i'm using the inputmask module. And some tricks to disable totally the `#city` input (no direct focus, no tabulation and no focus on invalidity possible) I had to do my own "disabled" because the "disabled" attribute also disables the "required" attribute. I think I can somehow patch it by using empty customValidity, but i've no clue how.

Comment: maybe you could check if it is displayed before ? check if is empty the validate div or with a boolean true if you have displayed it before ?

Comment: @JordiJordi I've already tried it, the problem with that is that it doesn't display anymore after then. I want it to displays everytime when i submit the form (like any other invalidation message) but not when i keyup on the input.

Comment: why u dont reload the boolean value when you submit the form ? then it will show the custom validation another time; boolean isShowed = false; $("form").submit(function(){ isShowed = false;}) ...

Comment: Ok @JordiJordi I tried it. The problem with that, is that i discovered that putting an empty customValidity makes the input valid. What i tried is : putting a global boolean to false, onClick on the submit button : put this boolean to false, on keyup on the input : check if this boolean is false : put it to true and setCustomValidity, else : setCustomValidity empty

Comment: Ok the problem is, you want it show the message, first time that the user press keyup, and later disapear since the form is submited  ? then reinicialice it ?

Comment: No, i want to show it every time the user submits the form while the input is invalid, but i don't want it to show on keyup at all (i've edited my last comment with what i tried)

Comment: Then why you dont show the   $('#zip_code')[0].setCustomValidity("Veuillez renseigner un code postal valide."); when  he click the form submmiting ? if you make it inside a keyup event's ajax answer it is checked every keyup, validate it on submit event not at keyup ?

Comment: @JordiJordi I tried it , and in plenty of other ways, but didn't figure out how to make it work :/ can you show me a code with whay i should put in keyup and what in submit plz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ... i think i forgot some close if's, but the idea is separate the validation from the keyup, and check it at form submit

```
var zipCode = "";
$("#your-form-id").submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
       zipLength = zipCode.split('_')[0].length

   if (zipLength < 5 || zipLength == 5 && $( this ).val().split('_')[0].length != 5) {
    zipCode = $( this ).val();
    $('#city').replaceTag('<input>', true);
    $('#city').addClass('disabled');
    $('#city').focus(function(){$("#zip_code").focus();});
    $('#zip_code')[0].setCustomValidity("Veuillez renseigner un code postal 
 valide.");
 $('#city').attr('tabindex', -1);
    $('#city').attr("placeholder", zipCode.length == 0 ? "Ville" : "Aucune 
ville pour 
ce code postal");
$('#city').html('');
 return false; // it make the form no submit, if postal code is wrong then the form dont submit
 }
});

$('#zip_code').keyup(function() {



    if (zipCode.length == 5) {
        $.ajax( {
            url: "an url to a json representating every city having the zipCode",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
     `enter code here`       data: {
                zipCode: zipCode
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                data.cities.map( function( x, i ) {
                    let cityName = x.name.charAt(0) + x.name.substr(1).toLowerCase().trim();
                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (data.cities.length > 1) {
                            $('#city').removeClass('disabled');
                            $('#city').replaceTag( '<select>', true );
                            $("#city").append( new Option( cityName, cityName, true ) 
);
                        } else {
                            $('#city').addClass('disabled');
                            $('#zip_code')[0].setCustomValidity("Veuillez renseigner 
un code postal valide.");
                            $('#city').focus(function(){$("#zip_code").focus();});
                            $('#city').val( cityName );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("#city").append( new Option( cityName, cityName ) );
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
    }
  }
 });
 $(":input").inputmask();
```

Comment: Good answer, but you forgot to change the state of #city when keyup on zip code, also no need to change its state on submit